# Series expansion of an integral

Tags: integration

I want to find the series expansion for the integral

\begin{align}
\int_{z}^\infty e^{-t^2}\, {\rm d}t &= \int_z^\infty \left(\frac1t\right)\left(te^{-t^2}\right)\,{\rm d}t \\
&=\left[-\frac1{2t}e^{-t^2}\right]_z^\infty -\int_z^\infty \frac1{2t^2}e^{-t^2}\,{\rm d}t\\
&= \frac{e^{-z^2}}{2z} - \int_z^\infty \frac1{2t^2}e^{-t^2}\,{\rm d}t
\end{align}

Now my tutor then jumps to the equality

$$\implies \int_{z}^\infty e^{-t^2}\, {\rm d}t = \frac{e^{-z^2}}{2z}\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{n!}{2^n(-2z^2)^n}+R_N(z)$$

where

$$R_N(z)=O\left(\int_z^\infty \frac{e^{-t^2}}{t^{2N+2}}\,{\rm d}t\right)$$

Now I attempted to find this by successive integration but the series I have found so far is

$$\int_z^\infty e^{-t^2}\,{\rm d}t = \frac{e^{-z^2}}{2z}-\frac{e^{-z^2}}{4z^3}+\frac{3e^{-z^2}}{8z^5}-\int_z^\infty\frac{15}{8t^6}e^{-t^2}\,{\rm d}t$$

and I don't really see this pattern arising. Has she gone wrong or am I integrating incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your terms are right so far.  But your tutor's formula is wrong.
It should be 
$$ \dfrac{e^{-z^2}}{2z} \sum_{n=0}^N \dfrac{ (2n)!}{n! (-4z^2)^{n}} + 
R_N(z) $$

Hint: use integration by parts to show that

$$ \int_z^\infty \dfrac{e^{-t^2}}{t^{2n}}\; dt = \dfrac{e^{-z^2}}{2 z^{2n+1}} - \frac{2n+1}{2} \int_z^\infty \dfrac{e^{-t^2}}{t^{2n+2}} \; dt $$

Comment: Ok, does it make any difference that $z\to\infty$? I have found this bottom integral and I understand how $R_N$ is found but I'm still confused on how the summation is found.

Comment: For any $N$, the formula with $R_N$ works for all $z > 0$.  But it's only really interesting as $z \to \infty$: for any fixed $z$, as $N$ increases $R_N(z)$ eventually gets very large.  That's why this is an asymptotic series rather than a convergent series.